# How do you Make A Repeat-Until Loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How do you Make A Repeat-Until Loop in C++? As opposed to a standard While or For loop. I need to check the condition at the end of each iteration, rather than at the beginning.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
do
{
  //  whatever
} while ( !condition );
```

Comment: Uhh ... This is pretty sad.  Emil hit submit sooner than I did ... The "accepted" should go to him ...

Comment: You have less rep, and it's an extremely simple question, so I'll gladly give it to you. :)

Comment: As jalf said, though: If you want an do until loop rather than a do while loop you'll have to negate the condition.

Comment: Thanks.  :)  It sill feels unfair, though.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help, you guys! SO is the best!

Comment: The code in the answer doesn't look like C++ code. Only if `null` is an instance of type `Planet`.

Comment: Sorry, I was more interested in getting the point across than in showing perfect C++ code.  Happy now?

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could do `#define repeat do` and `#define until(cond) while(!(cond))`, but anyone who resorts to that kind of preprocessor abuse should be shot.

Comment: #define true false and #define false true have always been among my favorites.

Comment: Please, do not use defines(even as a joke). Use template functions.
@Adrien, your code is better now, but `condition` still undefined ;)~~~

Answer (score 9):

When you want to check the condition at the beginning of the loop, simply negate the condition on a standard `while` loop:

```
while(!cond) { ... }
```

If you need it at the end, use a `do` ... `while` loop and negate the condition:

```
do { ... } while(!cond);
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use macros to simulate the repeat-until syntax.

```
#define repeat do
#define until(exp) while(!(exp))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure how the "exp" works though. Is it a generic wildcard? Thank you!

Comment: @Ace.C It's an argument name. The second `#define` makes a macro, which acts sort of like a function. So, in this case, `#define until(exp)` is a macro named `until` which takes a parameter `exp`, and expands to `while(!(exp))`.

Comment: Thank you @Conor.O , Is there perhaps and article or another post about this subject you could link me to? I'm having trouble finding good resources on how to make these sorts of macros

Comment: Please DON’T use the preprocessor to define your own language - unless you _really_ want the hatred of every co-worker who ever has to maintain your code.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
do
{
  //enter code here
} while ( !condition );
```

So what this does is, it moves your 'check for condition' part to the end, since the `while` is at the end. So it only checks the condition after running the code, just like how you want it

Answer (score 2):

For an example if you want to have a loop that stopped when it has counted all of the people in a group. We will consider the value X to be equal to the number of the people in the group, and the counter will be used to count all of the people in the group. To write the

> while(!condition)

the code will be:

> int x = people;
>
> int counter = 0;
>
> while(x != counter)
>
> {
>
> counter++;
>
> }
>
> return 0;

Answer (score 1):

Repeat is supposed to be a simple loop n times loop... a conditionless version of a loop.

```
#define repeat(n) for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 

repeat(10) {
    //do stuff
}
```

you can also also add an extra barce to isolate the i variable even more

```
#define repeat(n) { for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
#define endrepeat }

repeat(10) {
    //do stuff
} endrepeat;
```

[edit]
Someone posted a concern about passing a something other than a value, such as an expression. just change to loop to run backwards, causing the expression to be evaluated only once

```
#define repeat(n) { for (int i = (n); i > 0; --i)
```

Comment: Macros are almost always a bad idea. Here, imagine what happens if the macro is passed a complex expression.

Comment: just change the loop and done
for (int i = n; i >0  ; i--)

Answer (score 1):

This can also work

```
    int repeat;
    repeat = 0;
    //to repeat once
    do  {
       ....
       repeat + 1;
    } while(repeat < 1);
```

This is of course assuming you want to only repeat once, so you can change the value of repeat, not the amount of it's increase from the variable amount from the `while();` condition. This code works for C++ 17, but I am not sure for other versions.

Comment: It seems your answer is quite close to accepted one, so that's the point posting it?